# In Hadoop 2.0 era are name node and data node terminology still valid?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, bigdata

Hadoop 2.0 brought in YARN which replaced the tasks of Job Tracker and Task Tracker. YARN consist of Resource Manager(Scheduler, Application Manager...), Node Manager and Application Master.

Does the terminology of data node and name node still exist in hadoop 2.0 environment. If they do what do they mean and what are the functions of these nodes and who manages them. Plus any other useful information please feel free to add.

(ps: might be data node and name node are part of HDFS only and they have nothing to do **directly** with respect to job processing which is handled by YARN. )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you said name node and data node are related to the storage layer of hadoop(HDFS) and not to the processing layer(Map Reduce/Yarn). Name Node and data node are structured in a master/slave architecture where name node its the master and data nodes are the slaves. In a summary their functions are:

- Name node: store all the metadata of the file system, including file names, locations, permissions, sizes , mapping of files to blocks, avaliable blocks.
- Data node: they are the component responsible for the data itself .

So when you load  data to hadoop it will be stored in the data nodes , and the corresponding metadata(file names ,locations, permissions, creation dates, etc) will be stored and indexed in memory on the name node.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much while some may call them Master/Worker. In short Name node responsible for managing file system namespace (metadata through EditLog and FsImage) and regulates access to files by clients. Clients contact Name node while writing files (where to write, block size) but write them directly onto data nodes. Data nodes actually store the data locally. 
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html

And there is Name node HA feature available where there is a Active-hot standby support and fail-over is seamless ( Also Resource Manager HA ).